# How to extract prepended IV from ciphertext during AES decryption in dart

Tags: dart, encryption, base64, aes

I'm trying to use AES encryption & decryption (cbc mode) and am able to successful encrypt the input text and prepend the IV (encoded base64), but I can't get the decryption to work. I'm sure there's something glaringly wrong with my approach but I'm pretty new to all this and have been stuck for a while.

I'm getting an invalid padding character error on the base64 decode...

---Encryption---

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

//encrypt
String encryptString(String? text, String privateKey) {
  final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(privateKey); //32 chars
  final iv = encrypt.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);

  final e = encrypt.Encrypter(
      encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));

    final encrypted_data = e.encrypt(text!, iv: iv);

    return iv.base64 + encrypted_data.base64;
}
```

---Decryption---

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'dart:convert';

String decryptString(String? inputString, String privateKey) {
  final decodedIV = base64.decode(inputString.substring(0, 24));
  final decodedCipher = base64.decode(inputString.substring(24));

  final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(privateKey); //32 chars

  final iv = encrypt.IV.decodedIV;

  final e = encrypt.Encrypter(
      encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));


  final decrypted_data = e.encrypt(decodedCipher!, iv: iv);

  return decrypted_data;
}
```

Comment: The bugs is that you use `e.encrypt()` in your decryption method instead of one of the [`decryptXXX()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypter-class.html) overloads. Also note that usually the *raw* IV and the *raw* ciphertext are concatenated, not their Base64 encoded data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it working!